# Reading .txt into vector by char but not ignoring spaces

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, char, whitespace

I have it reading from the file and pushing it into a vector but it doesn't seem to read the spaces from the message.txt.  I'm working a simple program and need the file stored as a vector of chars instead of strings.  The message.txt file is just a few word sentence nothing special.  When I run the program it just outputs all the chars minus the spaces.  Thanks

Has to be chars stored in the vector.

```
    vector<char> originalFile;      
    char c;
    fstream startFile1;
    startFile1.open("message.txt");

    if (startFile1.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Opened";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File Not Opened";
    }

    while (startFile1 >> c)
    {
        originalFile.push_back(c);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < originalFile.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << originalFile[i];
    }
    cout << originalFile.size();
```

Comment: Use getline then iterate through the string and add the characters to the vector.

Comment: while (c = startFile1.get())

Comment: while (startFile1..get(c))

Comment: that seemed to fix it.  Thanks for the help

Comment: More to the point, `while (startFile1.get(c))`. Or better still, just use a `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` duo and initialize the vector via iterator pair from inception. [See it live here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2faf4405dd4931f5).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any text processing, just read the whole file in in one go:

```
ifstream f("message.txt", ios::binary | ios::ate);
size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(f.tellg());
f.seekg(0, ios::beg);
vector<char> buffer(size);
if (f.read(buffer.data(), size))
{
    // buffer now contains entire file contents
}
```